# FreeBSD 9.1 buildworld fails in libclangsema

Tags: freebsd, compiling

I just went thru and updated a dozen or so machines from 9.0-RELEASE to 9.1-RELEASE and the last one is dieing during `buildworld`:

```
c++  -O2 -pipe -I/usr/src/lib/clang/libclangsema/../../../contrib/llvm/include -I/usr/src/lib/clang/libclangsema/../../../contrib/llvm/tools/clang/include -I/usr/src/lib/clang/libclangsema/../../../contrib/llvm/tools/clang/lib/Sema -I. -I/usr/src/lib/clang/libclangsema/../../../contrib/llvm/../../lib/clang/include -DLLVM_ON_UNIX -DLLVM_ON_FREEBSD -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=\"i386-unknown-freebsd9.0\" -DDEFAULT_SYSROOT=\"\" -fstack-protector -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -c /usr/src/lib/clang/libclangsema/../../../contrib/llvm/tools/clang/lib/Sema/SemaExpr.cpp -o SemaExpr.o
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:108560: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
c++: Internal error: Killed: 9 (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <URL:http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/lib/clang/libclangsema.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/lib/clang.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/lib.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src.
[Exit 1 ]
```

Things I have tried:

```
rm -rf /usr/src/* && cvsup
rm -rf /usr/obj/*
```

`/etc/make.conf` is pretty benign at this point with most optimizations turned off:

```
# Optimize when possible based on CPU
#CPUTYPE?= pentium4

# Set optimization and use pipes to speed up compiles
#CFLAGS= -O -pipe
NO_CPU_CFLAGS=  true    # Don't add -march=<cpu> to CFLAGS automatically
NO_CPU_COPTFLAGS= true  # Don't add -march=<cpu> to COPTFLAGS automatically

# Set kernel compile with special options.
# CFLAGS is not applicable to kernel builds.
#COPTFLAGS= -O -pipe
```

I'm feeling a little dumb at this point; so any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Of the things you've tried, you don't say that you tried restarting the `make` operation. Did you? How much RAM is in the machine? How much swap? (If the compiler is running out of memory, it could explain a compiler crash.) And kind of a last resort, does forcing a single-threaded `make` help? (`make -j1 -B buildworld`) I include the latter because a) it would reduce memory use; and b) it just happened to work for me this very afternoon, trying to build cmake on FreeBSD 9.1. :)  (Commenting because I have no idea if any of this is the right fix, not having run into it myself.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll bet you're right about the memory. This is an antique box and I had no idea; but it's only got 384 Mb... [sigh]

Comment: It's easy to test, if you've got several gigs of free disk space to play with. Just [add a swap file](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/adding-swap-space.html). I'd suggest 4 GiB.

Comment: I think `clang` is a more efficient compiler. You might want to try `clang` instead of `gcc`. You should eventually make the switch since fBSD 10 will use `clang` by default. You can use `clang` now by modifying your `/etc/make.conf`

Comment: All set. Found some more RAM. btw: I thot 9.x already used clang by default? Thanks for pointing that out.